# isolate value out of html body after a key string using regex in JS

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an HTML Body and I'm trying to extract a value out of it that follows a key string in that same body. So in the body it says "foo" and after a while it will be followed by "bar". To make it more specific, I know what is around "bar" but I do not know the content of "bar" and it cannot be matched on it's content format.

**Body exapmple:**

```
<html>
  <head><title>Some title</title></head>
  <body>
    ...
    <dl>
      <dt> foo </dt>
      <dd> other thing that does not matter </dd>
      <dd class="bar-indicator"> bar </dd>
      <dt> other key </dt>
      <dd> other thing that does not matter </dd>
      <dd class="bar-indicator"> not the matching value </dd>
    </dl>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I already squash the html into a body without breaks and just spaces. What I want to do is to only get the "bar" as output.

Current solution:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^.*(foo <\/dt> <dd> other thing that does not matter <\/dd> <dd class="bar\-indicator"> )(.*?)(<\/dd>).*$');
return body.replace(pattern, '$2');
```

The " other thing that does not matter </dd>" is sort of overkill and I prefer not having to mention it. What would be a good solution to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use](https://regex101.com/r/oV9iK1/3) non-greedy "anything" quantifiers to simplify the regex. To match the contents of the closest-to-a-foo "bar-indicator" element:

```
foo.*?class="bar-indicator".*?>(.*?)<\/\w+>
```